# How can I change the MSMQ response queue name format in NServiceBus?

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I am trying to access an NServiceBus service on a work server from a client at home over a VPN connection. The message gets to the service OK but the response queue name has the format

DIRECT=OS:MyHomePCName\private$\MyClientQueueName

The reply message sits in the server's outgoing queue presumably because it can't resolve MyHomePCName. Can I change the response queue name when sending the message to the following format?

DIRECT=TCP:MyHomeIPAddress\private$\MyClientQueueName

Of course I still have the problem of sending the IP address for the VPN connection, but I'm only testing at the moment and don't mind hard coding that in the client for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSB should format it correctly if you put "$queueName@$homeIpAddress".  Here is the code it uses:

```
public static string GetFullPath(string value){

IPAddress ipAddress;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(GetMachineNameFromLogicalName(value), out ipAddress))
{
    return (PREFIX_TCP + GetFullPathWithoutPrefix(value));
}
return (PREFIX + GetFullPathWithoutPrefix(value));
```

}

Comment: I can't put the IP address on the InputQueue config element because of this check in NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport: if (machine.ToLower() != Environment.MachineName.ToLower()) throw...

Comment: Your right, looks like a bug, I'd open an issue on GitHub.  It should also be checking for IP.

Comment: I don't know how to do that on GitHub. Is it still alive on SourceForge?

Comment: SourceForge is officially dead and everything is on GitHub.  The code is under NServiceBus/NServiceBus and there should be an Issues tab right there.

Comment: OK thanks. I was scared off by the signup process since I have no plans to create a repository! Issue raised.

Comment: I've now committed functionality that will enable two-way TCP communication when you specify the MessageEndpointMapping using an IP address rather than machine name.